# KeyError: 0 in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

I'm training maskRCNN for 3 object classes, following the train_shapes samples in the git. I used VIA 2.0.8 to extract the image annotations to a JSON.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bbed02f10f39> in <module>
      3 for image_id in image_ids:
      4     image = dataset.load_image(image_id)
----> 5     mask, class_ids = dataset.load_mask(image_id)
      6     visualize.display_top_masks(image, mask, class_ids, dataset.class_names)

K:\Python\maskRCNN\samples\dining\dining.py in load_mask(self, image_id)
    186             mask[:, :, i] = mask[:, :, i] * occlusion
    187             occlusion = np.logical_and(occlusion, np.logical_not(mask[:, :, i]))
--> 188         # Map class names to class IDs.
    189         class_ids = np.array([self.class_names.index(s[0]) for s in polygons])
    190         return mask.astype(np.bool), class_ids.astype(np.int32)

K:\Python\maskRCNN\samples\dining\dining.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    186             mask[:, :, i] = mask[:, :, i] * occlusion
    187             occlusion = np.logical_and(occlusion, np.logical_not(mask[:, :, i]))
--> 188         # Map class names to class IDs.
    189         class_ids = np.array([self.class_names.index(s[0]) for s in polygons])
    190         return mask.astype(np.bool), class_ids.astype(np.int32)

KeyError: 0
```

This is the code that it calls upon:

```
def load_mask(self, image_id):
    """Generate instance masks for an image.
   Returns:
    masks: A bool array of shape [height, width, instance count] with
        one mask per instance.
    class_ids: a 1D array of class IDs of the instance masks.
    """
    # If not a dining dataset image, delegate to parent class.
    image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
    if image_info["source"] != "dining":
        return super(self.__class__, self).load_mask(image_id)

    # Convert polygons to a bitmap mask of shape
    # [height, width, instance_count]
    info = self.image_info[image_id]
    polygons = info["polygons"]
    count = len(info["polygons"])
    mask = np.zeros([info["height"], info["width"], count],
                    dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, p in enumerate(info["polygons"]):
        # Get indexes of pixels inside the polygon and set them to 1
        rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(p['all_points_y'], p['all_points_x'])
        mask[rr, cc, i] = 1

    # Handle occlusions
    occlusion = np.logical_not(mask[:, :, -1]).astype(np.uint8)
    for i in range(count-2, -1, -1):
        mask[:, :, i] = mask[:, :, i] * occlusion
        occlusion = np.logical_and(occlusion, np.logical_not(mask[:, :, i]))
    # Map class names to class IDs.
    class_ids = np.array([self.class_names.index(s[0]) for s in polygons])
    return mask.astype(np.bool), class_ids.astype(np.int32)
```

What is a KeyError? Is this a data structure error with my polygons variable?

Answer (score 0):

[Key errors and how to handle them](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/)

In short. Whatever polygons is, it seems to contain some kind of dictionary objects, which, when you loop through in the line `class_ids = np.array([self.class_names.index(s[0]) for s in polygons])` are assigned to `s` and then you try to access the key `0`, except there isn't one.

My advice would be to be to debug by working out what exactly `polygons` and each `s` in it, is. Then work out what exactly you're expecting `s[0]` to be. Without knowing what each `s` looks like it's hard to give a more specific solution.